# Odoo 13 zip all binary fields in a form and download it

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, listview, odoo, odoo-13

I have a form view in which there are 5 binary fields i.e. **4 are images and 1 is audio**. I need to zip these fields and the user should be able to download this from tree view for selected records, maybe from a button click or a new option in action dropdown. Is there a possible solution for this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have tried it using two buttons in form view, one for generating zip and one for downloading, but I need to download the same from tree view for multiple records.

```
def generate_zip(self):
crop_stage = request.env['crop.stage'].sudo().search([('id', '=', self.id)])

    for rec in crop_stage:
        directory = rec.crop_id.name
        print('directory name', directory)
        #parent_dir = r"odoo\custom_addons\farm_management\static\zip"
        parent_dir = r"E:\XAMPP\htdocs"
        print('parent dir', parent_dir)
        path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
        print("Directory '% s' created" % directory)
        print('Path', path)
        img = base64.b64decode(rec.image)
        img_conv = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img))
        print('img type', type(img_conv))
        print('img', img_conv)
        img_format = img_conv.format
        img_conv.save('{}/{}'.format(path, rec.image_name), format(img_format))
        print(img_conv.format)

        img1 = base64.b64decode(rec.image1)
        img1_conv = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img1))
        print('img type', type(img1_conv))
        print('img1', img1_conv)
        img1_format = img1_conv.format
        img1_conv.save('{}/{}'.format(path, rec.image1_name), format(img1_format))
        print(img1_conv.format)

        img2 = base64.b64decode(rec.image2)
        img2_conv = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img2))
        print('img type', type(img2_conv))
        print('img2', img2_conv)
        img2_format = img2_conv.format
        img2_conv.save('{}/{}'.format(path, rec.image2_name), format(img2_format))
        print(img2_conv.format)

        img3 = base64.b64decode(rec.image3)
        img3_conv = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img3))
        print('img type', type(img3_conv))
        print('img3', img3_conv)
        img3_format = img3_conv.format
        img3_conv.save('{}/{}'.format(path, rec.image3_name), format(img3_format))
        print(img3_conv.format)
        print('end path', path)

        folder_to_zip = path
        # folder_to_zip = '{}'.format(rec.crop_id.name)
        print('folder_to_zip', folder_to_zip)
        # write_path = "odoo/custom_addons/farm_management/static"
        temp_path = r"E:\XAMPP\htdocs"
        src_path = os.path.join(temp_path, directory)
        print(src_path)
        if not os.path.exists(src_path):
            os.makedirs(src_path)

        shutil.make_archive(src_path, 'zip', src_path)

        print('End')


@api.model
def download_zip(self):
    print('entered download_to_zip1')
    pass


#script to download
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(".download_file").click(function(){
             console.log("Clicked")
                   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("crop_name_fms");
                  console.log(x)
                  console.log(x[0].value)
                    console.log(x[0].innerText)

                  if(x[0].value != 'undefined')
                  {
                  console.log("first if")
                  console.log(x[0].value)
                    window.location.href = "http://localhost/"+x[0].value+".zip";
                  }
                  if(x[0].innerText != null)
                  {
                    console.log("second if")
                    window.location.href = "http://localhost/"+x[0].innerText+".zip";
                  }
            });
              </script>
```

Comment: Share your tried code.

Comment: Hi Dipen, Please check the edited version, this is done for folder creation and zip generation, just need to download the created zip for multiple records.